# How to limit the number of connections to a socket and trigger timeout on client (Python)

Tags: python, sockets

How can I set a limit on the number of connections that a server socket can accept at once? I want to be able to set a max number of connections, and then once that limit is reached, any further attempts from clients to connect will result in a timeout. So far, I have tried something like this for the server:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.setblocking(0)
sock.bind(address)
sock.listen(0)

connections = []

while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [])

    if readable and len(connections) < MAX_CONNECTIONS:
        connection, client_address = s.accept()
        connections.append(connection)
        # Process connection asynchronously
```

and for the client:

```
try:
    sock = socket.create_connection(self.address, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    sock.settimeout(None)
    print "Established connection."
except socket.error as err:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Socket connection error: " + str(err)
    sys.exit(1)

# If connection successful, do stuff
```

Because of the structure of the rest of the program, I have chosen to use a non-blocking socket on the server and I do not wish to change this. Right now, the clients are able to connect to the server, even after the limit is reached and the server stops accepting them. How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Would it be helpful if you accepted the connection but immediately closed it?

Comment: I would like to make it so that once the connection limit is reached, further connections do not fail immediately, since there is the chance that another client will disconnect before the timeout is reached.

Comment: Your select.select statement has essentially accepted the connection. Consider putting that statement inside a conditional based on the number of connections currently being served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there might be a slight misunderstanding of `select()` at play here. According to the manpage, `select()` returns file descriptors that are "ready for some class of IO operation", where ready means "it is possible to perform a corresponding IO operation without blocking".
The corresponding IO operation on a listening socket is `accept()`, which can only be performed without blocking if the OS already made the full TCP handshake for you, otherwise you might block waiting for the client's final ACK, for instance.

This means that as long as the listening socket is open, connections will be accepted by the OS, even if not being handled by the application.
If you want to reject connections after a set number, you have basically two options:

- simply accept and close directly after accepting.
- close the listening socket upon reaching the limit and reopen when done.

The second option is more convoluted and requires use of the `SO_REUSEADDR` option, which might not be the right thing in your case. It might also not work on all OSs, though it does seem to work reliably on Linux.

Here's a quick sketch of the second solution (since the first is pretty straightforward).

```
def get_listening_socket():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.setblocking(0)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5555))
    sock.listen(0)
    return sock

sock = get_listening_socket()

LIMIT = 1
conns = {sock}
while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(conns, [], [])
    if sock in readable: # new connection on the listening socket
        conn, caddr = sock.accept()
        conns.add(conn)
        if len(conns) > LIMIT: # ">" because "sock" is also in there
            conns.remove(sock)
            sock.close()
    else: # reading from an established connection
        for c in readable:
            buf = c.recv(4096)
            if not buf:
                conns.remove(c)
                sock = get_listening_socket()
                conns.add(sock)
            else:
                print("received: %s" % buf)
```

You may, however, want to rethink *why* you'd want to do this in the first place. If it's only about saving some memory on the server, than you might be over-optimizing and should be looking into syn-cookies instead.

Comment: does the number i pass to `listen` not affect this at all? if so, what is the point of passing a number to `listen`?

Comment: Also, what is socket.SOL_SOCKET? I couldn't find documentation on it

Comment: The manpage to `listen()` answers your question: "If a connection request arrives when the queue is full, the client **may** receive an  error with an indication of ECONNREFUSED or, **if the underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored** so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds."
Since you're probably using TCP, and TCP supports retransmission, we're in the second case and have to explicitly reject new connections (which actually kind of defeats a nice feature of TCP).

Comment: As for `SOL_SOCKET`, it only means you're changing options at the socket API level. You could, for instance, be changing options at the TCP level, for a specific socket. (again from the manpage ;) )