# 'Listen()' value in socket not worked

Tags: python, django, sockets

Im need is limited quantity the connections, in listen is set s.listen(2), but I don't see any exception and I can created three new connections and more. Where is the mistake?

```
def func():
    global addr

    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    port = 9000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(2)

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        if addr not in clients_addr:
            addr.append([conn, addr])

        current_addr = addr
        thread = Thread(conn, current_addr)
        thread.start()
```

Comment: The value in s.listen(2) the 2 just says the max number of back logged connections as in waiting connections. The reason you can get three or more is because they are active connections please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186725/how-to-limit-the-number-of-connections-to-a-socket-and-trigger-timeout-on-client